# Dividing a string

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list, i want to split the every string from "And" and join it to first action.

```
OLD_Txt=
["User enters validusername "MAXI" And password "768"",
"User enters phonenumber "76567898" And ZIPcode "97656"",
"User Verifys Country  "ENGLAND" And City "LONDON""]
```

I want my list look like this

New_Txt:

```
["User enters validusername "MAXI"", 
"User enters password "768"",
"User enters phonenumber "76567898"",
"User enters ZIPcode "97656"",
"User Verifys Country "ENGLAND"",
"User Verifys City "LONDON""]
```

Comment: ```OLD_Txt= [User enters validusername "MAXI" And password "768", User enters phonenumber "76567898" And ZIPcode "97656", User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" And City "LONDON"]

```
isn't the element not in quotes ```""```?

Comment: You need to elaborate the question a little.

Comment: Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OLD_Txt= [
    'User enters validusername "MAXI" And password "768"', 
    'User enters phonenumber "76567898" And ZIPcode "97656"', 
    'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" And City "LONDON"']

base_word = 'User '

new_text = []
for string_obj in OLD_Txt:
    first_part, second_part = string_obj.split('And')
    verb_for_second_part = first_part.split(' ')[1] 
    # from split you ll get ["User" "enters", "validusername", "MAXI"]
    # and you need text at index 1 i.e: verb_at_index
    new_text.append(first_part)

    second_part = base_word + verb_for_second_part + second_part
    new_text.append(second_part)

print(new_text)
```

**output**

```
['User enters validusername "MAXI" ', 'User enters password "768"', 'User enters phonenumber "76567898" ', 'User enters ZIPcode "97656"', 'User Verifys Country "ENGLAND" ', 'User Verifys City "LONDON"']
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you corectly, you want to [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) your strings.
So you really want to:

```
New_Txt = ' '.join(OLD_Txt)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).